# mod_rewrite, vhosts on Apache 2.2 (windows)

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, vhosts, elgg

I'm currently working on a new website and want to run Elgg (Elgg.org) on it. It's fully running on PHP5 and has a lot of rewrite rules defined in the .htaccess files. On the Elgg community I didn't found / get any answers, so I will try and ask them here.

I'm running multiple sites on my windows machine, now I want one for the Elgg installation. Let's say we put them on obc.example.com. I added the following lines to my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
# De New Elgg Environment

<VirtualHost *:*>
    DocumentRoot "C://htdocs/elgg/OBC"
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias obc.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is, when I run the Elgg installer (e.g.) direct to obc.example.com, eerything seems to work fine in the first place. I get a nice screen that ask me for the database stuff. When I submit the page I get the next screen in the process. This is for the credentials of the website I'm making. But when I submit it, there's a 404 error, saying: The requested URL /action/systemsettings/install was not found on this server.

This is caused by the rewrite engine. The Elgg troubleshooting docs tell me that this is. ;)

The problem is now: how can I tell apache to use the .htaccess file for the rewrite rules? ~But only for this domain? (vhost, obc.example.com)

Regards,

Douwe Pieter

Answer (score 1):

Read the [.htaccess files tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) on how to use .htaccess files.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need something like

```
<Directory "C://htdocs/elgg/OBC">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

You can change the `All` to something else to restrict what kinds of directives are allowed in `.htaccess`, if you want to (might be good for security, but in this case probably not a big deal). The details are at the link Gumbo provided.

Alternatively, you could just copy and paste the contents of the `.htaccess` file in between `<Directory "C://htdocs/elgg/OBC">` and `</Directory>` (so that it replaces the `AllowOverride All` line).

Answer (score 0):

Though elgg does not support this. If you are using a debian based linux ... http://narnarnar.com/elgg/elgg_1.5-1_all.deb  ... seemed to fix all my installation trouble. I installed it on ubuntu 9.04.

make sure you did an apt-get install virtual-mysql-server first.